# $a^4 = x^2 + y^2 (6+8b)$ solutions $(x,y)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given constants $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, can we find $(x,y)$ such that

$a^4 = x^2 + y^2 16(6+8b)$

has a solution?

---

Alternatively: consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[4\sqrt{-m}]$ with $m \equiv 6 \mod{8}$. I want to check if there are ideals of order $4$, i.e. $\mathfrak{a}^4$ is a principal ideal $(q)$.

Taking norms 
$$a^4 = N(\mathfrak{a}^4) = N((q))=N(x+y4\sqrt{-m}) = x^2 + y^2 16m = x^2 + y^2 16(6+8b)$$

Comment: $x=a^2$ and $y=0$ will work but I assume you are looking for solutions that have nonzero $\sqrt{-m}$ component.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize the rational solutions by taking lines through the point $(a^2,0)$ and intersecting them with the curve. From this you can write down a formula for $x$ and $y$ in terms of the slopes of these lines, and from that you should be able to figure out which points are integral.

Comment: Dear Thom, I don't completely follow your argument. Especially how to go from rational solutions to integral solutions. can you maybe sketch it out a bit more? Thanks in advance

Comment: The lines that pass through $(a^2,0)$ are of the form $x = my + a^2$, where $m$ is a rational number. Substituting for $x$ into the main equation, we can solve for $y$ in terms of $m$, and likewise for $x$.  For what values of $m$ are the resulting values of $x,y$ integral?